# Ajax refresh div after all data is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax refresh div function that refreshes a div in every 10 seconds. However, sometimes it loads div before it gets data from mysql. How can I make it wait 2 seconds after loading the div again?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateServers(){
    $('#content').load('servers.php #content').fadeIn();;
}
setInterval( "updateServers()", 10000 );
</script>
```

Comment: It sounds like you only want to call .fadeIn() after the ajax call has returned.  Since the call is asynchronous, then you should probably use the complete function callback built into .load()  see the documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are better of making a setTimeout after the data has been retrieved!

```
$("#content").load("servers.php #content", 
  function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if (textStatus == "success") {
         setTimeout( "updateServers()", 10000 ); // Will only occur once
    }
    if (textStatus == "error") {
         // oh no!
    }
  }
```

Comment: Both this and Danyu's worked but this one is more reliable. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the load method's callback function:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
     $('#content').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateServers(){

      //Put some delay before refresh
      setTimeout(function () {
               $('#content').load('servers.php #content').fadeIn();
      }, 2000);

    }
    setInterval( "updateServers()", 10000 );
    </script>
```